# AngularJS custom directive does not work with in Handlebars template

Tags: angularjs, handlebars.js

This is the code that works:

```
 <select-city country="US"></select-city>
```

This is the code that not works:

```
 <select-city country="\{{country}}"></select-city>
```

For testing, I made this:

```
\{{country}}
```

It correctly prints US.

Note: I have to use `\` because I use Handlebars template.

Comment: does <select-city country="\US"></select-city> work?

Comment: use  `<select-city country=" '\' + {{country}}"></select-city>`

Comment: Sorry to reply late. But, country=" '\' + {{country}} would do the trick.

Comment: Can't you handle `\\` part in directive??

Comment: country="\US"=> \us.  and 
country=" '\' + {{country}}" => '\'

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line:

```
<select-city country="\{{country}}"></select-city>
```

To the following:

```
<select-city country="'\' + {{country}}"></select-city>
```

---

If you need to do this several times, it may be interesting to write a custom getter in order to avoid doing this in the view:

```
$scope.getCountry = function() {
    return '\\' + $scope.country;
}
```

In the view:

```
<select-city country="{{getCountry()}}"></select-city>
```

Comment: Great solution.

Comment: what I get is '\'

Comment: @Kinny Can you try `country="'\' + country"`? Did you tried the solution using the controller function?